# Wordpress get custome page URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I just get started with WordPress. I have customized WordPress default theme 'Twenty_Thirteen' and it's working fine.

```
Using WordPress 3.6.1
```

I have added a `custom page` at `localhost/wordpress/mypage`:

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content">
Hi! this is my custome page

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Problem:**

When I am directing to this URL

```
localhost/wordpress/mypage
```

it's giving me to 404

**Questions:**

- Am I missing something
- Why it's giving 404, even when page `mypage.php` is existing
- Is there any function in WordPress to get these page's URL

  How to do it without any plugin

I read some articles but haven't found any relevant to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try prepending a `/` to your file path. Without a path relative to root, it will try and navigate to that path relative to current.

> /localhost/wordpress/mypage.php

Comment: Can you open up your web server log and post the last few lines? That may point to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the page URL like:

$page = get_page_by_path( 'mypage' );

or

$page = get_page_by_title( 'mypage' );

then

```
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page); ?>">Page Link</a>
```

Comment: not working, I haven't created this page with WordPress. I have uploaded it from outside

Answer (score 0):

**Custom Page Template**

Create a template that can be used by any Page

**File Name:**

Name your template file so you can easily identify its Template Name, e.g., filename `my-custom-page.php` for template name `"My Custom Page"`.

Don't use `page-` prefix as WordPress will interpret the file as a specialized page template

**Syntax:**

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: My Custom Page
 * Description: A Page Template with a darker design.
 */

// Code to display Page goes here...
```

Source : [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template)

**How to Use Custom Page:**

- Create a page
- See right sidebar
- Scroll to `Page Attribute->Templates`
- Select Template for your page

**Note:** Must be careful with filename and page template top comments it will tells WordPress to register page template